# How to optimize subquery

Tags: mysql, select, count, distinct

I have a query with multiple subqueries to count how many users involved in a certain transaction depends on status.

```
SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT
    DATE(changes.created_at) AS `date`,
    SUM(IF(changes.status = 15, 1, 0)) AS installed_daily,
    SUM(IF(changes.status = 3, 1, 0)) AS port_reserved,
    (
      SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT created_by) FROM applicant_state_changes
      WHERE DATE(created_at) = DATE(changes.created_at) AND status = 3
    ) AS user_port_reserved,
    SUM(IF(changes.status = 5, 1, 0)) AS document_validated,
    (
      SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT created_by) FROM applicant_state_changes
      WHERE DATE(created_at) = DATE(changes.created_at) AND status = 5
    ) AS user_document_validated,
    SUM(IF(changes.status = 7, 1, 0)) AS account_created,
    (
      SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT created_by) FROM applicant_state_changes
      WHERE DATE(created_at) = DATE(changes.created_at) AND status = 7
    ) AS user_account_created,
    SUM(IF(changes.status = 11, 1, 0)) AS jo_created,
    (
      SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT created_by) FROM applicant_state_changes
      WHERE DATE(created_at) = DATE(changes.created_at) AND status = 11
    ) AS user_jo_created
    FROM applicant_state_changes AS changes
    GROUP BY DATE(changes.created_at)
    LIMIT 100 OFFSET 0
) a
ORDER BY date ASC;
```

This takes around 130 secs. Without the subqueries, my query takes up to 0.5 sec only.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can use conditional aggregation using case when expression

```
 SELECT
    DATE(changes.created_at) AS `date`,
    SUM(IF(changes.status = 15, 1, 0)) AS installed_daily,
    SUM(IF(changes.status = 3, 1, 0)) AS port_reserved,
    count(distinct case when status = 3 then created_by end) as user_port_reserved
    ,
    SUM(IF(changes.status = 5, 1, 0)) AS document_validated,
    count(distinct case when status = 5 then created_by  end) AS user_document_validated,
    SUM(IF(changes.status = 7, 1, 0)) AS account_created,
    count(distinct case when status = 7 then 1 end) AS user_account_created,
    SUM(IF(changes.status = 11, 1, 0)) AS jo_created,
    count(distinct case when status = 11 then created_by  end) AS user_jo_created
    FROM applicant_state_changes AS changes where 
    GROUP BY DATE(changes.created_at)
    LIMIT 100 OFFSET 0
```

Comment: The problem is I'm counting the DISTINCT created_by.

Comment: @SeeMore, I've changed it - you can check now

Comment: Thanks. Result duration is now 0.5 sec.